# sending data to my online MySQL database from my android app zxing

Tags: java, android, mysql, regex

I am building a simple QR Code reader using Zxing framework and so far it works fine. The issue here being that i have failed to find the variable for the captured QR code data. How can i send the captured QR code data to my online MySQL database.

Below is my code

Main_activity.java

```
    package io.github.akodiaemmanuel.mapenziscanner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;


import com.google.zxing.Result;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.ViewFinderView;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

/**
 * Created by Akodia Emmanuel on 9/18/2017.
 */

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    private ZXingScannerView mScannerview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        mScannerview = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(mScannerview);
        mScannerview.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerview.startCamera();
    }
    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
//Do anything with the result here
        Log.w("handleResult",result.getText());
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
        builder.setMessage(result.getText());
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        //resume scanning
        //mScannerview.resumeCameraPreview(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: what issue you are facing your question is **unclear**

Comment: Where is PHP, mysql  code in your question?

Comment: You can send the datas to a PHP page that will save these datas in your MySQL database

Comment: you don't have php in your code as it stands the question is unclear

Comment: @Ludo how can i send the data to a PHP page. i have liked that idea actually. But can an android app have a php file in it

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile i never knew one can add PHP to a java program

Comment: @NileshRathod I want to capture the qr code data from the program but i do not now where it is. And i am new to java

Comment: @akortian488 in your question you have tagged php

Comment: Read about AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the datas to a PHP script that will save these datas in your MySQL database:

To send data to PHP from Android, you can use https://github.com/koush/ion

Here we wiil call the page url_to_my_script.php and send qrdata in POST. When the page is loaded (onCompleted) we get the JSON response and do something depending on the response.

Android:

```
Ion.with(context)
    .load("url_to_my_script.php")
    .setBodyParameter("qrdata", qrdata)
    .asJsonObject()
    .withResponse()
    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<JsonObject>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<JsonObject> reponse) {
            Log.i("myactivity", "jsonresult is " + reponse);
            //if we have an error or code
            if (e != null || reponse.getHeaders().code() != 200) {
                Log.e("myactivity", "Error invalid request" + e);
                Log.e("myactivity", "response code:"+reponse.getHeaders().code());                                  
            } else {
                if (!success.equals("1")) {
                    String error = result.get("error_message").toString();
                }else{
                    //everything is ok do something
                }
            }
     }
});
```

Php script:

THis PHP script get the data and return a JSON response

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
require_once 'database_config.php';

function insertMyData($data){
   //do something
   // if ok return true else false
}

if($_POST){
    $qrdata= trim($_POST['qrdata']);
    if(insertMyData($qrdata)){
        echo '{"success":1}';
    }else{
        echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Put a message her"}';
    } 
} else {
    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Invalid date"}';
}
?>
```